# How do I display an image preview in modal?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

My component like this :

```
<input type="file"
   ref="file"
   @change="onFileChange"
   class="d-none"
   :accept="accept">
<button type="button" @click="selectFile">
```

My methods like this :

```
  methods: {
    selectFile(){
      this.$refs.file.click()
    },
    onFileChange(e) {
      let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) {
        return
      }
      this.fileName = files[0].name
      this.createImage(files[0])
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var image = new Image()
      var reader = new FileReader()

      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.file = e.target.result;
        this.$emit('change', this.file)
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
  }
```

My full code and demo like this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/JjGNGgg

When the user clicks the upload image button, it displays the filename. I want if I click on the filename, it will display a preview image in the form of modal

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break down the problem into smaller issue to solve:

1. Create a modal and bind css style object to it.
   You can bind css styling to this div

```
<div id="image-preview" :style="previewStyle"></div>
```

The style object for displaying responsive image can be:

```
      previewStyle: {
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
        display: 'none',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundImage: ''
      }
```

You then later update the backgroundImage with the appropriate url when the file is uploaded.

2. Trigger modal to display/close with the image button (bind :click event to

```
<p class="filename">{{ fileName }}</p>
```

to activate modal (basically update the 'display' property on the style object above.
3. Modal must display preview of the selected image.
The most important part here is to get the URL of the blob object uploaded, to do this you can use JS and target the file upload input:

```
const imgSrc = URL.createObjectURL(this.$refs.file.files[0]);
```

And update the backgroundImage url with imgSrc

Here's an example of how it's done:

https://codepen.io/duongph/pen/MWKmybL

Comment: Thanks. But I want if I click on the filename, it will display a preview image in the form of modal dialog

Comment: Hi,
I think you might need to get some more basics on html/css/js. Maybe review this article about making a modal first. After that you can combine with the code sample and create what you want.